# Is there a way to integrate an dilog flow cx agent with Skype?

Tags: python, node.js, chatbot, skype, dialogflow-cx

Hi I was wonder if is posible to integrate an dialogFlow CX agent with skype? Im researched but I have not found nothing up to date. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As Skype is not a built in integration for Dialogflow CX you need you need to create your own integration I recommend looking for how to create your own custom integration and then integrating it with skype or any other service you want

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow CX does not have a built-in integration for Skype. You can check the [Integrations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration) documentation for a complete list of the supported integrations in Dialogflow CX.

However, for any unsupported platforms, if they provide developer tools, you can create your own implementation and make calls to Dialogflow's API. You can check the [Interaction with APIs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api) documentation for some [examples](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api#detect-intent) showing how to call the detectIntent method.

To create your own implementation/integration, you can use one of Dialogflow CX’s [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview), [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3-overview?hl=en), or [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3?hl=en).